# How to make the views to allocate the same percentage of the screen always?

Tags: android, svg

Well, i searched a lot but i have not been able to find how can make my views to always have the same percentage of the screen alocated to them. May be i am using wrong keywords for search.

Anyways, I have 3 images. I want to make sure that they are always fit to the screen. All of them currently have 200dp height and 200dp width.

In wider screens they are seen like this:

[image]

However, in smaller screens they are shown like this:

[image]

I am totally ok if images size gets decreased but i have to have the all of the 3 images always shown on the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: use LinearLayout with layout_weight?

Comment: Try to use LinearLayout with weight property

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a vertical `LinearLayout` with layout_weihth on it's children views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/first_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/second_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/third_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For responsive design try to use `ConstraintLayout` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) and use sdp unit for size [here](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using ConstraintLayout with layout_constraintDimensionRatio property like below:
Note: I haven't tested below code, but it should work fine.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="second_image"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/second_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="third_image"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="first_image"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/third_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="second_image"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```